# Default arguments in lambda function

Tags: python, function, lambda, default, anonymous

```
import time
from functools import partial
(lambda fun:fun())(partial(time.sleep,2))
#runs, sleeps 2 seconds
partial(lambda fun:fun(),partial(time.sleep,2))()
#runs, sleeps 2 seconds
```

`partial` was used to give default argument 2 to `sleep`, which runs as `fun()`, and was given as an argument to lambda function, which
was run by `()`.

But how to give default argument to lambda function without `partial`, so that `()` also could run it like `(lambda fun:fun(),defaultargument)()`?

(I passed a function as a default argument.)

Comment: What's the point of `lambda fun: fun()` in the first example? `partial` already returns a callable, you've already deferred execution. And what are you expecting from the second example?

Comment: I would like to make a lambda function like
l=(lambda x:x)
l(1)

but I want to make something like
l=(lambda x:x,1)
so that I could just run
l(), because 1 was a default argument

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me, sorry.